# scikit-learn GridSearchCV returns ValueError: continuous is not supported

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am trying to run the `scikit-learn` tool `GridSearchCV`, but the following code

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 

X, y = make_regression(
    n_features=5, n_informative=3, n_samples=200)

params = {'n_estimators': range(1, 100),
          'learning_rate': [.01, .1, .2, .5, .7, .9, .99, 1]}

optRegressor = GridSearchCV(
    AdaBoostRegressor(), params,
    scoring = 'accuracy', cv = 5, n_jobs = -1, verbose=3)

optRegressor.fit(X, y)
```

returns

```
ValueError: continuous is not supported
```

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771440/gridsearchcv-on-a-working-pipeline-returns-valueerror?rq=1) has a similar problem, but the answer is to convert pandas dataframes to numpy arrays. I am already using numpy arrays, so this does not apply.

The problem in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047525/valueerror-continuous-is-not-supported) is linked to the score used. But the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) states, regarding the `scoring` parameter that

> If None, the estimator’s score method is used.

So the scoring method used should be, by default in this case, the [`AdaBoostRegressor.score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostRegressor.score). This scoring method is obviously a regression score, so that solution doesn't work either.

---

How can I run the GridSearchCV on this example?

Comment: But you are using `scoring = 'accuracy'`, not `None`, so you are overiding the default value with an inappropriate score function, hence the error.

Comment: As is, the issue is due to the inappropriate `scoring = 'accuracy'` function used, and the question is a duplicate of the second linked thread.